# JSON wrong loop output in Python

Tags: python, json, loops

I am playing with JSON format and there is a small problem with this (very simple) code.

```
import json

bol = []
caus = []
num = []

idx = 0
count = [idx]
while idx < 10:
    idx += 1

    bollettini = \
        {
            'Nome bollettino': 'Bollettino ' + str(idx)
        }

    causale = \
        {
            'Causale': str(idx)
        }

    numero = \
        {
            'Numero': str(idx)
        }

    bol.append(bollettini)
    caus.append(causale)
    num.append(numero)

    data = (bol+caus+num)
    json_data = json.dumps(data)

    print(json_data)
```

It prints out this:

```
[{"Nome bollettino": "Bollettino 1"}, {"Causale": "1"}, {"Numero": "1"}]
[{"Nome bollettino": "Bollettino 1"}, {"Nome bollettino": "Bollettino 2"}, {"Causale": "1"}, {"Causale": "2"}, {"Numero": "1"}, {"Numero": "2"}]
[{"Nome bollettino": "Bollettino 1"}, {"Nome bollettino": "Bollettino 2"}, {"Nome bollettino": "Bollettino 3"}, {"Causale": "1"}, {"Causale": "2"}, {"Causale": "3"}, {"Numero": "1"}, {"Numero": "2"}, {"Numero": "3"}]
[{"Nome bollettino": "Bollettino 1"}, {"Nome bollettino": "Bollettino 2"}, {"Nome bollettino": "Bollettino 3"}, {"Nome bollettino": "Bollettino 4"}, {"Causale": "1"}, {"Causale": "2"}, {"Causale": "3"}, {"Causale": "4"}, {"Numero": "1"}, {"Numero": "2"}, {"Numero": "3"}, {"Numero": "4"}]
[{"Nome bollettino": "Bollettino 1"}, {"Nome bollettino": "Bollettino 2"}, {"Nome bollettino": "Bollettino 3"}, {"Nome bollettino": "Bollettino 4"}, {"Nome bollettino": "Bollettino 5"}, {"Causale": "1"}, {"Causale": "2"}, {"Causale": "3"}, {"Causale": "4"}, {"Causale": "5"}, {"Numero": "1"}, {"Numero": "2"}, {"Numero": "3"}, {"Numero": "4"}, {"Numero": "5"}]
[{"Nome bollettino": "Bollettino 1"}, {"Nome bollettino": "Bollettino 2"}, {"Nome bollettino": "Bollettino 3"}, {"Nome bollettino": "Bollettino 4"}, {"Nome bollettino": "Bollettino 5"}, {"Nome bollettino": "Bollettino 6"}, {"Causale": "1"}, {"Causale": "2"}, {"Causale": "3"}, {"Causale": "4"}, {"Causale": "5"}, {"Causale": "6"}, {"Numero": "1"}, {"Numero": "2"}, {"Numero": "3"}, {"Numero": "4"}, {"Numero": "5"}, {"Numero": "6"}]
[{"Nome bollettino": "Bollettino 1"}, {"Nome bollettino": "Bollettino 2"}, {"Nome bollettino": "Bollettino 3"}, {"Nome bollettino": "Bollettino 4"}, {"Nome bollettino": "Bollettino 5"}, {"Nome bollettino": "Bollettino 6"}, {"Nome bollettino": "Bollettino 7"}, {"Causale": "1"}, {"Causale": "2"}, {"Causale": "3"}, {"Causale": "4"}, {"Causale": "5"}, {"Causale": "6"}, {"Causale": "7"}, {"Numero": "1"}, {"Numero": "2"}, {"Numero": "3"}, {"Numero": "4"}, {"Numero": "5"}, {"Numero": "6"}, {"Numero": "7"}]
[{"Nome bollettino": "Bollettino 1"}, {"Nome bollettino": "Bollettino 2"}, {"Nome bollettino": "Bollettino 3"}, {"Nome bollettino": "Bollettino 4"}, {"Nome bollettino": "Bollettino 5"}, {"Nome bollettino": "Bollettino 6"}, {"Nome bollettino": "Bollettino 7"}, {"Nome bollettino": "Bollettino 8"}, {"Causale": "1"}, {"Causale": "2"}, {"Causale": "3"}, {"Causale": "4"}, {"Causale": "5"}, {"Causale": "6"}, {"Causale": "7"}, {"Causale": "8"}, {"Numero": "1"}, {"Numero": "2"}, {"Numero": "3"}, {"Numero": "4"}, {"Numero": "5"}, {"Numero": "6"}, {"Numero": "7"}, {"Numero": "8"}]
[{"Nome bollettino": "Bollettino 1"}, {"Nome bollettino": "Bollettino 2"}, {"Nome bollettino": "Bollettino 3"}, {"Nome bollettino": "Bollettino 4"}, {"Nome bollettino": "Bollettino 5"}, {"Nome bollettino": "Bollettino 6"}, {"Nome bollettino": "Bollettino 7"}, {"Nome bollettino": "Bollettino 8"}, {"Nome bollettino": "Bollettino 9"}, {"Causale": "1"}, {"Causale": "2"}, {"Causale": "3"}, {"Causale": "4"}, {"Causale": "5"}, {"Causale": "6"}, {"Causale": "7"}, {"Causale": "8"}, {"Causale": "9"}, {"Numero": "1"}, {"Numero": "2"}, {"Numero": "3"}, {"Numero": "4"}, {"Numero": "5"}, {"Numero": "6"}, {"Numero": "7"}, {"Numero": "8"}, {"Numero": "9"}]
[{"Nome bollettino": "Bollettino 1"}, {"Nome bollettino": "Bollettino 2"}, {"Nome bollettino": "Bollettino 3"}, {"Nome bollettino": "Bollettino 4"}, {"Nome bollettino": "Bollettino 5"}, {"Nome bollettino": "Bollettino 6"}, {"Nome bollettino": "Bollettino 7"}, {"Nome bollettino": "Bollettino 8"}, {"Nome bollettino": "Bollettino 9"}, {"Nome bollettino": "Bollettino 10"}, {"Causale": "1"}, {"Causale": "2"}, {"Causale": "3"}, {"Causale": "4"}, {"Causale": "5"}, {"Causale": "6"}, {"Causale": "7"}, {"Causale": "8"}, {"Causale": "9"}, {"Causale": "10"}, {"Numero": "1"}, {"Numero": "2"}, {"Numero": "3"}, {"Numero": "4"}, {"Numero": "5"}, {"Numero": "6"}, {"Numero": "7"}, {"Numero": "8"}, {"Numero": "9"}, {"Numero": "10"}]
```

It is different from what I want to achieve, which is this kind of output:

```
[{"Nome bollettino": "Bollettino 1"}, {"Causale": "1"}, {"Numero": "1"}]
[{"Nome bollettino": "Bollettino 2"}, {"Causale": "2"}, {"Numero": "2"}]
[{"Nome bollettino": "Bollettino 3"}, {"Causale": "3"}, {"Numero": "3"}]
[{"Nome bollettino": "Bollettino 4"}, {"Causale": "4"}, {"Numero": "4"}]
```

and so on until the condition is satisfied.

How to do it ?

Thanks

Comment: Clear `bol`, `caus`, `num` at the start of each loop.

Comment: You append to the same lists without clearing them. I suppose it's not intended.

Comment: @aaron can you tell me how ? post some code or show me where to modify...thanks

Comment: Move `bol = []` and the next 2 lines into the `while` loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import json

idx = 0
count = [idx]
while idx < 10:
    bol = []
    caus = []
    num = []
    idx += 1

    bollettini = \
        {
            'Nome bollettino': 'Bollettino ' + str(idx)
        }

    causale = \
        {
            'Causale': str(idx)
        }

    numero = \
        {
            'Numero': str(idx)
        }

    bol.append(bollettini)
    caus.append(causale)
    num.append(numero)

    data = (bol+caus+num)
    json_data = json.dumps(data)

    print(json_data)
```

This should do.

The solution is either to empty the list `bol`, `caus` and `num` each time, or initialise them within the `while`.

Comment: That's it. Selected as answer because of the explanation. Also the other answers are good.
Thanks guys.

Comment: Little OT: look at the desired output result. Do you know how to create a single JSON from it ? Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like below:

```
json_data = []
idx = 0
while idx < 10:
    idx += 1

    data =[ {
            'Nome bollettino': 'Bollettino ' + str(idx)
        },
        {
            'Causale': str(idx)
        },
        {
            'Numero': str(idx)
        }]
    json_data.append(data)
print(json_data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work.  Just make sure you put all of your variables into a list and append that to your final list of lists.

```
import json

idx_range = 10
data = []
for idx in range(1, idx_range):
    bollettini =  {'Nome bollettino': 'Bollettino ' + str(idx)}
    causale = {'Causale': str(idx)}
    numero = {'Numero': str(idx)}
    data.append([bollettini, causale, numero])
    json_data = json.dumps(data)
    print(json_data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Or like this:

```
import json


idx = 0
count = [idx]
data = []
while idx < 10:
  idx += 1

  bollettini = {'Nome bollettino': 'Bollettino ' + str(idx) }
  causale    = {'Causale': str(idx) }
  numero =     {'Numero': str(idx)  }


  data.append([bollettini]+[causale]+[numero])

json_data = json.dumps(data)
print (json_data) #added parenthesis
```

Comment: works too... Do you know how to create, from this output, a single JSON ?

Comment: this new version creates a single json a 2d array

Comment: Awesome man. You're the best. Post it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46976665/merge-multiple-json-into-single-one-python) and link also this question. For me it's the answer of the other question. Thanks