# Merge multiple JSON into single one (Python)

Tags: python, json, merge

I am searching for a way to merge multiple JSONs into a single one. My output is in this format:

```
[{"Nome bollettino": "Bollettino 1"}, {"Causale": "1"}, {"Numero": "1"}]
[{"Nome bollettino": "Bollettino 2"}, {"Causale": "2"}, {"Numero": "2"}]
[{"Nome bollettino": "Bollettino 3"}, {"Causale": "3"}, {"Numero": "3"}]
[{"Nome bollettino": "Bollettino 4"}, {"Causale": "4"}, {"Numero": "4"}]
[{"Nome bollettino": "Bollettino 5"}, {"Causale": "5"}, {"Numero": "5"}]
[{"Nome bollettino": "Bollettino 6"}, {"Causale": "6"}, {"Numero": "6"}]
[{"Nome bollettino": "Bollettino 7"}, {"Causale": "7"}, {"Numero": "7"}]
[{"Nome bollettino": "Bollettino 8"}, {"Causale": "8"}, {"Numero": "8"}]
[{"Nome bollettino": "Bollettino 9"}, {"Causale": "9"}, {"Numero": "9"}]
[{"Nome bollettino": "Bollettino 10"}, {"Causale": "10"}, {"Numero": "10"}]
```

Every single line is a valid JSON. I a looking for a way to do it in Python, like [this site](http://tools.knowledgewalls.com/onlinejsonmerger) do.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46975135/json-wrong-loop-output-in-python) you can find the code I am using to generate JSON data.

I have tried to use `jsonmerge` and `json-merger` but it's not so effective. The site above do the work perfect but I need to do it in Python.

Particularly, with `jsonmerge` using [the syntax from the documentation](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jsonmerge), the output is only the first two values...

```
result = merge(bollettini, causale, numero)
print(result)

{'Nome bollettino': 'Bollettino 1', 'Causale': '1'}
{'Nome bollettino': 'Bollettino 2', 'Causale': '2'}
{'Nome bollettino': 'Bollettino 3', 'Causale': '3'}

etc...
```

...which are not even JSON's.

How to merge them ?

Comment: Why do you not include `"Numero"`?

Comment: Which format would you like the output JSON to be ?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem It's the output of "jsonmerge" not mine..

Comment: @ZdaR I don't know what do you mean. It should be a valid JSON format. Thanks

Comment: This is also a valid JSON format: `[{}]`, what are you precisely looking for ?

Comment: @ZdaR  Try to validate the second output. The first one it's ok, but I want to made of it a single JSON which contains all the strings.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-to-merge-two-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression

Comment: Based on your previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46975135/json-wrong-loop-output-in-python), which is obviously related, why don't you create a `list` with all your lines and then call `json.dumps()` on this `list` ? Essentially @NareshChaudhary's answer.

Comment: @Unatiel so, made a list of `json_data` (from related question..) and then dump it ? Just did it now but it's not valid as JSON...

Comment: @Link I tried too based on said answer, and I cannot reproduce your issue on python 3.6. I took the output of `json.dumps(json_data)` and every single JSON validator I've tried say it outputs a valid RFC4627 JSON.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or like this with a 2D array output.

```
import json


idx = 0
count = [idx]
data = []
while idx < 10:
  idx += 1

  bollettini = {'Nome bollettino': 'Bollettino ' + str(idx) }
  causale    = {'Causale': str(idx) }
  numero =     {'Numero': str(idx)  }


  data.append([bollettini]+[causale]+[numero])

json_data = json.dumps(data)
print (json_data) #added parenthesis
```

Comment: The answer is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46975135/json-wrong-loop-output-in-python).

Answer (score 1):

Say you have multiple jsons as list of lists like

```
l = [[{"Nome bollettino": "Bollettino 1"}, {"Causale": "1"}, {"Numero": "1"}]
[{"Nome bollettino": "Bollettino 2"}, {"Causale": "2"}, {"Numero": "2"}]
[{"Nome bollettino": "Bollettino 3"}, {"Causale": "3"}, {"Numero": "3"}]
[{"Nome bollettino": "Bollettino 4"}, {"Causale": "4"}, {"Numero": "4"}]
[{"Nome bollettino": "Bollettino 5"}, {"Causale": "5"}, {"Numero": "5"}]
[{"Nome bollettino": "Bollettino 6"}, {"Causale": "6"}, {"Numero": "6"}]
[{"Nome bollettino": "Bollettino 7"}, {"Causale": "7"}, {"Numero": "7"}]
[{"Nome bollettino": "Bollettino 8"}, {"Causale": "8"}, {"Numero": "8"}]
[{"Nome bollettino": "Bollettino 9"}, {"Causale": "9"}, {"Numero": "9"}]
[{"Nome bollettino": "Bollettino 10"}, {"Causale": "10"}, {"Numero": "10"}]]
```

You just need to chain the lists to form a single one! Read more on `itertools.chain` [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable)

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(l))
```

after dumping your data as json
Output:

```
[{"Nome bollettino": "Bollettino 1"}, {"Causale": "1"}, {"Numero": "1"}, {"Nome bollettino": "Bollettino 2"}, {"Causale": "2"}, {"Numero": "2"}, {"Nome bollettino": "Bollettino 3"}, {"Causale": "3"}, {"Numero": "3"}, {"Nome bollettino": "Bollettino 4"}, {"Causale": "4"}, {"Numero": "4"}, {"Nome bollettino": "Bollettino 5"}, {"Causale": "5"}, {"Numero": "5"}, {"Nome bollettino": "Bollettino 6"}, {"Causale": "6"}, {"Numero": "6"}, {"Nome bollettino": "Bollettino 7"}, {"Causale": "7"}, {"Numero": "7"}, {"Nome bollettino": "Bollettino 8"}, {"Causale": "8"}, {"Numero": "8"}, {"Nome bollettino": "Bollettino 9"}, {"Causale": "9"}, {"Numero": "9"}, {"Nome bollettino": "Bollettino 10"}, {"Causale": "10"}, {"Numero": "10"}]
```

Comment: It's not valid according to jsonlint

Comment: @Link Sorry, I don't get it. Can you please explain what do you mean by `not valid`?

Comment: Paste the output to [jsonlint](https://jsonlint.com/). It will give an invalid JSON.

Comment: Ah! That was because, the output that I pasted had single quotes `'` instead of double quotes!  `"` and that was because, for testing I copy pasted your input to a string and then processed it to get the lists! I've corrected the output!

Answer (score 1):

... it is quite unclear what you want have, may that helps:

```
input = [
    [{"Nome bollettino": "Bollettino 1"}, {"Causale": "1"}, {"Numero": "1"}],
    [{"Nome bollettino": "Bollettino 2"}, {"Causale": "2"}, {"Numero": "2"}],
    [{"Nome bollettino": "Bollettino 3"}, {"Causale": "3"}, {"Numero": "3"}],
    [{"Nome bollettino": "Bollettino 4"}, {"Causale": "4"}, {"Numero": "4"}],
    [{"Nome bollettino": "Bollettino 5"}, {"Causale": "5"}, {"Numero": "5"}],
    [{"Nome bollettino": "Bollettino 6"}, {"Causale": "6"}, {"Numero": "6"}],
    [{"Nome bollettino": "Bollettino 7"}, {"Causale": "7"}, {"Numero": "7"}],
    [{"Nome bollettino": "Bollettino 8"}, {"Causale": "8"}, {"Numero": "8"}],
    [{"Nome bollettino": "Bollettino 9"}, {"Causale": "9"}, {"Numero": "9"}],
    [{"Nome bollettino": "Bollettino 10"}, {"Causale": "10"}, {"Numero": "10"}]
]

result = []
for line in input:
    result.append({k:v for x in line for (k,v) in x.items()})
```

result:

```
[{'Causale': '1', 'Nome bollettino': 'Bollettino 1', 'Numero': '1'},
 {'Causale': '2', 'Nome bollettino': 'Bollettino 2', 'Numero': '2'},
 {'Causale': '3', 'Nome bollettino': 'Bollettino 3', 'Numero': '3'},
 {'Causale': '4', 'Nome bollettino': 'Bollettino 4', 'Numero': '4'},
 {'Causale': '5', 'Nome bollettino': 'Bollettino 5', 'Numero': '5'},
 {'Causale': '6', 'Nome bollettino': 'Bollettino 6', 'Numero': '6'},
 {'Causale': '7', 'Nome bollettino': 'Bollettino 7', 'Numero': '7'},
 {'Causale': '8', 'Nome bollettino': 'Bollettino 8', 'Numero': '8'},
 {'Causale': '9', 'Nome bollettino': 'Bollettino 9', 'Numero': '9'},
 {'Causale': '10', 'Nome bollettino': 'Bollettino 10', 'Numero': '10'}]
```

Comment: It's not valid according to jsonlint.

Comment: Yes, this is a Python object. You need to use `json.dumps(result)` to recieve a valid JSON string !